# Write inside text area with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, innerhtml

I am trying to write something in text area when I click on a link.

```
function writeText(txt){
    document.getElementById("writeArea").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

I would like to pass html tag in place of txt as parameter to this function so that I can get image, link etc inside text area. Is it possible in Javascript? || JQuery will be good?
Pre-thanks.

Comment: Your function satisfies your requirement. You can use simple string or html tags as a string in txt variable. jQuery internally uses same mechanism you used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render some images and anchor tags on the screen then don't use a textarea. Use any other container like `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>` etc.

```
$("#yourelementid").html(yourtext);
```

will put the text (in your case HTML) inside the element with id yourelementid

HTML

```
<p id="para1"></p>
```

jQuery

```
var txt = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
$("#para1").html(txt);
```

See a [**working sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/wPMvX/)

Comment: Thank you Rahul, now I got the idea.

Answer (score 5):

Or if jquery tag was there for a reason:

```
$('#writeArea').val(txt);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `value`:

```
document.getElementById("writeArea").value = txt;
```

Comment: hmm... but when I passed <code> txt = "This is what I <a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo is here </a>Funny</p>have to say about"; <code> then the output inside <textarea id="writeArea"> is : - This is what I <a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo is here </a>Funny</p>have to say about; but I want to see link there.

Comment: @user510050: That is impossible. HTML is not rendered inside `<textarea>`'s.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it in jQuery if you just want to set the text of a textarea:

```
$("#yourid").val("hello");
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/quQqH/

If you're looking to have HTML in it then it needs to be a container element (such as a `div`).

```
// Html
<div id="yourid"></div>

//JavaScript
$("#yourid").html('<a href="#">My link</a>');
```

Otherwise, another option is to have a Rich Text Editor (like [Yahoo Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)) so that it renders the HTML that's in the textarea input - this will make it user editable. This is slightly more complicated, as you'll need to include the correct files to make the editor work. Then just do something like the following:

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor('yourid', {
    height: '200px',
    width: '350px',
    toolbar: 0 // Hides the toolbar
});
myEditor.render();


$("#yourid").val("Click for <a href='http://yahoo.com'>Yahoo</a>");
```

You can see this working: http://jsfiddle.net/quQqH/1/. In this case, I've removed the toolbar by setting it to 0 but it is customisable to show different buttons, etc. Just remove that line to display the default toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, in that text area, what I would like to do is: - $("#yourid").val("hello <a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo is here!</a>"); I want to pass this, and want  to get link to the Yahoo side inside text area.

Comment: If you want to have an editable box, then you need to use something like TinyMCE (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) for WYSIWIG editing. However, if you're just trying to add links to your page then the `<textarea>` should be a HTML container like a `div`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example of rich text editing.

Answer (score 0):

just give like this

```
$("#ID").val("<img src='images/logo.png' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write long text in the textarea, you can use this way:

HTML

```
<textarea id="theId"></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
var a = 'Test textarea content. <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>" ';

$("#theId").val(a);
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3pVk8/)**